# Types for Firestore triggered cloud function params?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So here are the available triggers for Firestore cloud functions:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions

**onCreate**

```
functions.firestore
.document('my-collection/{doc-id}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => { /* ... */ });
```

**onDelete**

```
functions.firestore
.document('my-collection/{doc-id}')
.onDelete((snap, context) => { /* ... */ });
```

**onUpdate**

```
functions.firestore
.document('my-collection/{doc-id}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => { /* ... */ });
```

**onWrite**

```
functions.firestore
.document('my-collection/{doc-id}')
.onWrite((change, context) => { /* ... */ });
```

I'm converting my project to Typescript. What types should I use for the params `change` `context` and `snap`?

Comment: TypeScript should infer the types of the parameters without you doing anything in the code.  If your code editor is smart about TS, it should show you the inferred types.

Comment: Thanks, Doug. Did not know that. That's because I was declaring my functions in separate files and out of the `function.firestore.document().onUpdate()` triggers. I was only adding this part in `index.ts` where I was importing and re-exporting them inside the triggers. But will use it like this from now on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are the types:

**onCreate:**

```
snapshot: FirebaseFirestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot
context: functions.EventContext
```

**onDelete:**

```
snapshot: FirebaseFirestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot
context: functions.EventContext
```

**onUpdate:**

```
change: functions.Change<FirebaseFirestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot>
context: functions.EventContext
```

**onWrite:**

```
change: functions.Change<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentSnapshot>
context: functions.EventContext
```

---

More details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore_) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext) in the doc.

---

If you are using Typescript, you would import/use like this:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
...

export const fnSomeCollectionTriggerOnUpdate = 
functions.firestore.document('somecollection/{docId}')
  .onUpdate(async (change: functions.Change<admin.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot>,
               context: functions.EventContext) => {
...
}
```

Comment: Do you know type for 'context', when used in an onCall?